# Question regarding the Supervised Principal Components method

Tags: pca, survival, cox-model

I'm going over Bair's and Tibshirani's [Supervised PC method](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/bair.pdf) and looking at their R package tutorial [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/superpc/tutorial.html).  In their paper, in the section titled "A Breast Cancer Example,"  it seems they find the most relevant genes using a univariate Cox test on the training set (78 patients), and then train a Cox Model on the testing data (292 patients) with PCA transformed features.  I'm a little confused on why they trained on the testing data.  If the goal is prediction of survival times of the testing data, wouldn't data fitted using the testing data severely bias the test predictions?

It seems in the tutorial they do the same thing where after they find the optimal threshold hyperparameter, they fit a cox model on the test data set using the command: `superpc.fit.to.outcome(train.obj, data.test, fit.cts$v.pred)`.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, and any input in the right direction would be appreciated.